# prevent clang-format from indenting lambdas

Tags: clang-format

what clang-format makes:

```
 QObject::connect(&w, &sap::Window::keyPress, [&w](auto* event)
                 {
                     if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
                         w.close();
                 });
```

what i want:

```
QObject::connect(&w, &sap::Window::keyPress, [&w](auto* event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
    w.close();
});
```

is there a way i can make clang-format NOT indent lambda bodies? can't find anything about it in the documentation.

this is what i have so far:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM,
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman,
NamespaceIndentation: All,
SpaceBeforeParens: Never,
AccessModifierOffset: -4,

AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false,
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false,
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None,
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false,
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false,

ColumnLimit: 100,
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true,
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 9999,
IndentWidth: 4,
PointerAlignment: Left
```

Answer (score 1):

which version on `clang-format` are you using?

the default configuration on recent version (`v3.9.0` or v`3.8.0`) does almost what you want:

```
QObject::connect(&w, &sap::Window::keyPress, [&w](auto *event) {
  if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
  w.close();
});
```

you can try it online: http://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/

but for longer argument packs, the default config returns:

```
QObject::connect(sender, &sap::ClassName::signalName, receiver,
                 &sap::OtherClass::slotFunc,
                 [this](auto dummy, const auto* event) {
                     if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
                         doStuff();
                 });
```

by `.clang-format` like this:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentWidth:  4
ColumnLimit:  80
Language:     Cpp

AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
BinPackArguments:      false
BinPackParameters:     false

PointerAlignment:      Left
```

you'll get:

```
QObject::connect(&w, &sap::Window::keyPress, [&w](auto* event) {
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
        w.close();
});

QObject::connect(
    sender,
    &sap::ClassName::signalName,
    receiver,
    &sap::OtherClass::slotFunc,
    [this](auto dummy, const auto* event) {
        if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
            doStuff();
    });
```

at the moment, `BraceWrapping` has no special member for lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering in 2021, there is a `LambdaBodyIndentation` option since Clang 13. The behavior OP wants can be achieved with

```yaml
LambdaBodyIndentation: OuterScope
```